# GitLab Configuration for Local Users

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I just finished installing GitLab and I think the interface is great. I have a few questions for configuring it though.

Previously this server used the most basic ssh management for git. In other words, users would log in using ssh and check out code from a directory like `ssh://user@server:/Git/repo.git`, Users would need to belong to the Linux group "`gitusers`" for this to work.

My questions:

1. Instead of creating users through the gitlab interface, I would like to allow anyone who belongs to the gitusers group to be able to log in using their linux account credentials and see their repositories, is this possible?
2. I would like SSH clones to work in a similar way. Right now, the ssh link that is listed on a repository on gitlab says to use `ssh://git@server:user/repo.git` I would like that to be user@server. It is fine if the directory itself is something that GitLab manages.
3. Is there a way to expose a `git://` style link from gitlab?

In other words, instead of changing the work flow to match gitlab, I would like to use the GitLab GUI on top of our existing workflow. Any tips for how to change configurations to solve these two issues would be a huge help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. GitLab needs to be able to have the user defined in its user database in order to associate him/her to the repos. The authentication is a different matter and can be delegated to an LDAP, an [apache server](https://serverfault.com/a/544349/783), or many [other mechanisms](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Custom-omniauth-provider-configurations).
2. ssh will *always* use git as a user: the all idea is for the user to *never* directly access the remote server shell. The public key of the user registered in their GitLab account will be enough to authenticate them.
3. No, `git://` protocol doesn't support authentication, which means GitLab wouldn't be able to process any `git://` url query.

Comment: I am looking into the PAM auth. for gitlab but it looks like it may not be possible to make it work without a lot of modifications. Do you know of another gitlab like web UI that supports this better? As I mentioned in the post, I'd like a UI on top of our normal worflow rather than changing the workflow to match what the UI wants to do. Thanks a lot for your reply